# Story-identification: Programmer working on animal AIs has his work destroyed

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story which came out in the 90s or earlier.

A programmer is working day and night on AIs for a simulation of lions & other savannah animals.  He keeps having problems because when they get smart enough to hunt, they start killing the prey just for fun, not just to survive.

At some point, a disgruntled former colleague/employee somehow destroys his work with a bomb involving an elevator/pizza delivery.

Comment: Not this, but possibly of interest; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Veldt_(short_story)

Comment: Simulated lions have to kill prey to survive?

Comment: @user14111 They do if that's part of the simulation, yes.  It would be simple enough to code them with, say, a "nutrition" value, which degrades over time, kills them if it gets too low for too long, and refills when they "kill" simulated prey.  There are plenty of real-world software ecosystem simulations that do that or something very similar (though they don't run into the problem the story posits, probably because they're not designed as *evolutionary* AIs).

Comment: In fact, there is an entire area of simulation called "predator prey models" which deals with exactly this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Pipes" by Robert Reed, collected in The Year's Best Science Fiction, Ninth Annual Collection (ed. Gardner Dozois)

The narrator is a programmer working  from home on simulations of Ice Age ecosystems as part of efforts to bring back historical megafauna.

He hires a Native American plumber who sees his work and comments how he'd love to return to the land and take only what he needed. The narrator snaps back that his ancestors didn't take only what they needed and that's why the megafauna are extinct in the first place.

> The plumber winds up lowering a pipe bomb into the server room, eliminating the project, and telling the narrator's boss to tell him, "The redskins did it again!"